# Alter urls within a tag

Tags: php, regex, hyperlink, str-replace

I'm hit a bit of a noob wall and i'm not certain how to get over it.

When displaying some content from a DB, this content will contain HTML tags.
One of those tags is `<a>` link.

Its href will equal any of the following.

```
http://www.example.com
http://www.example.com/
http://www.example.com/some/other/stuff
/some/other/stuff
/
www.example.com
www.example.com/
```

What i need to do, and i've tried the logic using str_replace() but i cant get it 100% working... is turn all the above links to this.

```
http://www.example.com/2012_2013
http://www.example.com/2012_2013/
/2012_2013/some/other/stuff
/2012_2013
www.example.com/2012_2013
www.example.com/2012_2013/
```

my issue is mainly with turning

```
/some/other/stuff
```

into

```
/2012_2013/some/other/stuff
```

when i have no idea what `/this/could/be` so how do i find it and prepend `/2012_2013`

This does not seem to be working 100%

```
$content = str_replace("http://www.example.com/","http://www.example.com/2012_2013/",$wData['field_id_2']);                                     
$content = str_replace('href="/"','href="/2012_2013/"',$content);
echo $content;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And those folders actually exists in your system, right?

Comment: No, they are URLs to other pages.

Comment: http://php.net/parse_url is your friend. don't trying to build your own regex when PHP already does all that for you. That plus DOM to actually FIND the `<a>` tags and get their src and you'll be set.

Comment: Thanks, i'll look into parse_url. Something to learn :).

Comment: Please select an answer for this question.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) by `/` and append `2012_2013` at the right place, then [implode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) the array.

So something like this:

```
$link = '<a href="http://www.example.com/some/other/stuff">http://www.example.com/some/other/stuff</a>';

$linkParts = explode('/', $link);
$linkParts[2] = $linkParts[2] . '/2012_2013';
$linkParts[7] = $linkParts[7] . '/2012_2013';

$finalLink = implode('/', $linkParts);

echo $finalLink;
```

With the above I am assuming your domain format does not change.

This looks a like a database content issue. It's probably best to update them correctly in your database and you won't need to fiddle around with the output.

Comment: Unfortunately, too many people are handling the content and keeping it uniform throughout would be close to impossible. But the explode idea sounds great. I'll give that a shot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With the help of `parse_url` function, following code should work for you.

```
$arr = array('http://www.example.com', 'http://www.example.com/',
'http://www.example.com/some/other/stuff', '/some/other/stuff',
'/some/other/stuff/', '/2012_2013/some/other/stuff', '/', 'www.example.com',
'www.example.com/');

$ret = array();
foreach ($arr as $a) { 
   if ($a[0] != '/' && !preg_match('#^https?://#i', $a))
      $a = 'http://' . $a;
   $url = parse_url ($a);
   $path = '';
   if (isset($url['path']))
      $path = $url['path'];
   $path = preg_replace('#^((?!/2012_2013/).*?)(/?)$#', '/2012_2013$1$2', $path );
   $out= '';
   if (isset($url['scheme'])) {
      $out .= $url['scheme'] . '://';
      if (isset($url['host']))
         $out .= $url['host'];
   }
   $out .= $path;
   $ret[] = $out; 
}

print_r($ret);
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://www.example.com/2012_2013
    [1] => http://www.example.com/2012_2013/
    [2] => http://www.example.com/2012_2013/some/other/stuff
    [3] => /2012_2013/some/other/stuff
    [4] => /2012_2013/some/other/stuff/
    [5] => /2012_2013/some/other/stuff
    [6] => /2012_2013/
    [7] => http://www.example.com/2012_2013
    [8] => http://www.example.com/2012_2013/
)
```

Comment: This looks great with the assumption i can provide the url's directly. Unfortunately i'll have a whole block of text and html from which i wont be able to extract just the links. That's originally why I attempted str_replace(); But great example of parse_url. Thanks!

Comment: While I understand your requirement but it is almost impossible to detect `/` and `/some/other/stuff` etc as URL in a block of HTML.

Comment: I figured it wasn't going to be easy. I guess i'll just get as close too 100% as i can. Thanks!